# Are there languages/cultures which use a different mental framing of note pitch than "low/high"?

Tags: terminology, pitch

It occurred to me recently that the way we refer to the pitch of notes is somewhat arbitrary. We refer to notes with a low frequency as "low" and notes with a high frequency as "high."

This doesn't have to be this way. We could perhaps refer to the relationship as slow/fast, wide/thin, big/small, or even high/low if referencing the period instead of the frequency. Do any cultures or languages use a different mental construct for pitch?

If so, does it have any impact on the way they interact with music? If not, is this from cultural mixing leading to one ubiquitous system, or because there's something inherently compelling about the low/high framing for human minds?

Comment: I have no expertise on this whatsoever, but intuitively I would say that it stems from the experience of singing. When you sing a low note, you feel the vibration deeper in your throat.

Comment: Looking at the numbers involved when describing the *frequency* of notes, the 'low' notes have low numbers, and the 'higher' have higher frequencies. So, high/low makes the most sense, surely?

Comment: @Tim I can't find anything definitive, but I suspect the naming convention of low/high pitch predates the understanding and measurement of sonic waves.

Comment: @Tim Looking at the numbers involved when describing the *wave length* of notes (which is by the way an understanding that is significantly older than frequency) the "low" notes have high number (or long lengths) and the "higher" notes have lower numbers. In this sense high/low suddenly become quite counterintuitive.

Comment: @Lazy Also to be noted that a "longer" string will have a "lower" note, everything else being equal ;)

Comment: @Tom This is in fact the same thing, as string length and wavelength correlate.

Comment: This is an interesting question, and also a question I have absolutely not idea about. Some things though: It is not necessary to have the concept of notes as we have it. And in a culture that does have a completely different concept of pitch there is always the danger that the terms "high note" and "low note" are culturally adopted alongside with the concept of notes.

Comment: This seems, indeed, a deeper question than I first thought! +1

Comment: This was discussed in the first day of Music Theory 101 for me. The teacher pointed out that the notion of "up and down in pitch-space" was culturally construed; I think they suggested that there was some speculation that this is because we have to "work harder" with our muscles to sing higher, just as we work against gravity to lift an object. I'm afraid I don't have the references, or know offhand of a different system, but the idea is out there.

Comment: (It's important for teachers of young children to understand, too; before they can know that they're singing/playing "too high" or low, they have to have the concept of up/down in pitch-space taught and trained.)

Comment: In English there is also “sharp” and “flat”. I don’t know any other language that uses this geometric metaphor.

Comment: See also the [linguistics.se] take on it: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/11872/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, and you don't even need to move far from English. In Norwegian, “høy lyd” (literally “high sound”) denotes a *loud* noise, and “lav lyd” means soft sound. To describe a high-pitched sound, you'd say “lys lyd” (literally “bright sound”), to describe a low-pitched one you'd say “mørk lyd” (“dark sound”). The same terminology is also found to some level in old-fashioned German (“heller Klang” ≈ bright⇒high-pitched), though in general German use the pitch axis is also labelled like in English (“hoch” vs “tief”).

Comment: Huh, Dungeons & Dragons never told me that tieflings translate to "lowfolk"/"underworld folk" - they just told me they're part demon and left it at that.

Answer (score 2):

Ancient Greek music ordered notes by frequency but in reverse order from what is done now. The best reason I read (but I don't remember where) was that the Greek stringed instruments were strung much like modern guitars; the high-frequency notes were placed near the player's feet and the low-frequencies notes were placed near the head.

When a modern guitar is held in a normal (right-hand stringing) position, the bass strings are higher on the body (of the person) than the soprano strings. This may be the reason that the Greeks called bass notes "high" and soprano notes "low." (Different instruments than the modern ones though.)

Other contrasting words could have been used, (male-female, soft-hard, granite-chalk, tall-short, fat-thin, etc.). (As an aside,) over the years, Western theorists have referred to anacrusis as both "female" or "male" patterns and melodies lacking anacrusis as "male" or "female."

Comment: The Greeks used their word for "low" for what we call "high frequency" and vice versa. Their terms match the way guitars, ukes, and some other stringed instruments are strung. Modern guitars are the same; the "low" notes are gravitationally tighter than the hight notes (but lower frequency wise.)

Comment: This prompts another question: Did the Greeks describe pitches as "high" and "low", or were they just using those words to refer to the placement of the strings?

Comment: "*Oxys*, 'Sharp', is standard Greek for 'high-pitched' as well as for 'pointed' or 'keen-edged'; its musical opposite, *barys*, 'low-pitched', means 'heavy' (not 'blunt') when applied to solid bodies. The metaphor of 'high' and 'low' in pitch is seldom found in Greek sources.... The usual contrast is between 'sharp' and 'heavy', which are not even polar opposites. This suggests a way of conceiving (even or perceiving) pitch that is interestingly different from ours. (Andrew Barker, *Greek Musical Writings: II, Harmony and Acoustic Theory* [Cambridge University Press, 1989], 69n2).